# Send a struct using socket over http

Tags: c, sockets, http

I want to transfer a struct (has data and ID etc.) over http using send() and recv(). Over TCP the following two lines works perfectly.

```
Client:　send(sock, (char *)&StructToSend, sizeof(StructToSend), 0);
Server:　recv(sock, (char *)&StructToRecv,  sizeof(StructToRecv),0);
```

But when over HTTP, the StructToRecv gets only two bytes messy code like this:  ÈÈ

```
    ////Client code: send over http
    int length = 0;
    char header[4096];
    char tmp_name[80];
    memset(tmp_name, 0, sizeof(tmp_name));
    strcat_s(tmp_name, "tmp.txt");

    length  = (sizeof(SendStruct)+strlen(tmp_name)+ 287);

    sprintf_s(header, "POST /%s/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n", sub_dir;
    sprintf_s(header, "%sHost: %s \r\n", header , szIP);
    sprintf_s(header, "%sUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0\r\n", header);
    sprintf_s(header, "%sAccept: text/html;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n", header);
    sprintf_s(header, "%sAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n", header);
    sprintf_s(header, "%sAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n", header);
    sprintf_s(header, "%sConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n", header);
    sprintf_s(header, "%sContent-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------26774670897926\r\n", header);
    sprintf_s(header, "%sContent-Length: %d\r\n", header, length );
    sprintf_s(header, "%s\r\n", header);  //blank line
    sprintf_s(header, "%s-------------------------------26774670897926\r\n", header);
    sprintf_s(header, "%sContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n", header, tmp_name);
    sprintf_s(header, "%sContent-Type: text/plain\r\n", header);
    sprintf_s(header, "%s\r\n", header);  //blank line
    sprintf_s(header, "%s%s\r\n", header,  (char *)&StructToSend );
    sprintf_s(header, "%s-------------------------------26774670897926\r\n", header);
    sprintf_s(header, "%sContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"submit\"\r\n", header);
    sprintf_s(header, "%s\r\n", header);
    sprintf_s(header, "%sSubmit\r\n\r\n", header);
    sprintf_s(header, "%s-------------------------------26774670897926--\r\n\r\n\0", header);      

    send(sock, header, sizeof(header), 0);


    ////Server code : recv over http 
    char http_data[4096] = { '\0' };
    ZeroMemory( http_data, sizeof( http_data));
    recv(sock,  http_data,  4096, 0);
```

Comment: One of your `sprintf_s()` calls is missing a close parenthesis; there's no way the code shown compiles.  The C11 Annex K definition of `sprintf_s()` is: `int sprintf_s(char * restrict s, rsize_t n, const char * restrict format, ...);`  Even though Microsoft probably doesn't quite match that (`int sprintf_s(char *buffer, size_t sizeOfBuffer, const char *format [, argument] ... );`, you're cheating horribly by not passing a size as the second argument. You also cannot reliably pass the target string (`header`) as one of the arguments to be processed — it yields undefined behaviour.  **Rethink!**

Comment: Note that sending a struct this way (over HTTP, TCP, or any other protocol) is not recommended, because the in-memory layout of the struct is not guaranteed to be the same on both sides of the network connection, and if it differs, then the receiver will misinterpret the incoming data.  The correct way to send data is either as text, or member-data-item by member-data-item so that the over-the-wire data format will be well defined.  (Many programmers choose to use a serialization library to handle this task for them)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I'm not supposed to use third library. How can I fix that?

Comment: Data serialization is its own topic, so I can't provide an adequate answer in a comment, but here is a link to get you started:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+serialize+data+%5Bc%5D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> sprintf_s(header, "%s%s\r\n", header,  (char *)&StructToSend );
> ```

You are using `sprintf(...%s..)`. This means the data you give are treated as a char string terminated with `\0`, i.e. only data up to the first `\0` will be included.

Comment: What should I use? Any suggestions with code please?

Comment: Should I convert StructToSend to a char string first?

Comment: @MinKim: you cannot use any string functions like sprintf, strcpy, strlen etc with binary data containing `\0`.  String functions are for (non-binary) strings only, for everything else use memcpy and similar functions.

Comment: You also should not even attempt sending binary struct representation over the wire. A recipe for disaster.

Comment: Can you please write code for example? My struct contains int, DWORD, and data (for transferring files content )

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm not sure I understand. The header contains string for "POST /%s/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n" and the struct. How can I mix them into a string then send and recv?  Use memcpy?

Comment: @MinKim: A string in C is defined to end with `\0` which means you cannot have a string containing `\0` inside and thus you cannot use any string functions. send and recv don't take strings as argument but memory buffers and the size of the buffer, and thus the end of the buffer is defined by the size only. And yes like I said already, use memcpy and similar function because they work on buffers not strings.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  Thanks so much. But the buffer to send is like httpheader-struct-httpheader, can you write code example to illustrate your idea please?  I really don't know how to use memcpy to combine string and buffer into one thing. I 'm so confused.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I tried your example but it doesn't work.  I think I will try that serialize thing. Thank you so much!